# How to align row flex elements in columns?

Tags: css, flexbox

I use `flex` to align my elements. `#sentinels` is the outermost container and each line of `div` (green in the example below) has the class `line`.

```
#sentinels {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.line {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

This gives

[image]

I would like, however, to have the `div` aligned in columns:

[image]

Is such a setup possible with `flex`?

Comment: is it possible to update the html code also ?

Comment: @MostafaBaezid: yes, however the number of rows is not known

Comment: just for test run. like your picture

Comment: @MostafaBaezid: sorry, I though you meant to ask whether I have control over the HTML part (which I do). The source is complex because the components are generated on the fly via JS so I resorted to a picture rather than a set of  generated `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this https://jsbin.com/jevaqovaga/edit?html,css,output. Outer div with width 100% for each inner div could solve your problem.

Comment: Just an FYI, this requires that the columns be smaller than their row containers.  In this example, if the `inner` is larger than 33% of the total width, it will offset and things won't match up.